# Asynchronous running of Python functions

Tags: python, file-io

I have a function that will (based on parameters) move/rename image files from a mapped card reader drive in Windows to a server drive after the file is renamed using a template and appending the incrementing number from the for loop.

There are usually three cards of photos that will be sent to the destination folder. Currently each card is being processed one after the other which because of the file sizes and traveling over the network can take quite some time.

is there a way to have a function that would receive a list of the mapped card drives (not more than 3) and then run the rename function simultaneously for each card.

My poor attempt to illustrate what I am trying to do follows:

```
def collectCards(cards):
    for card in cards:
         #my goal would be to run each instance of the following function asynchronously
         drv =renameImages(card)

def renameImages(cardDrive):
    #perform renaming functions
    return count_of_renamed_images
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) with processes (`Pool`) or threads (`pool.ThreadPool`). In both cases, the only difference is in the import - the API stays the same:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

my_pool = Pool(3)
# `cards` is a list of cards. Send rename requests to workers.
my_pool.map(renameImages, cards)

# Close the pool and wait for processes to close.
my_pool.close()
my_pool.join()
```

The number in `Pool(3)` indicates number of worker processes - more means greater number of concurrent renameImages functions running. Bear in mind that `multiprocessing` requires `card` objects to be able to be pickled. If `renameImages` is not heavy on memory, you could try using `ThreadPool` - `card` objects are then shared between threads.